# Specify user access control by URL in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, url, user-controls, access

I'd like to specify permissions for a **group of users** for a **URL** in Sharepoint 2013.

For instance, permissions for the URL at **www.mysharepoint.com/wiki**:

1. 'Administrator' group can edit wiki at www.mysharepoint.com/wiki
2. 'Manager' group can view wiki at www.mysharepoint.com/wiki
3. All other groups has no access (no view, no edit) at www.mysharepoint.com/wiki

I'd like to specify such permissions for every other URL I have for my SP 2013. These links can be:

- www.mysharepoint.com/files/folder1
- www.mysharepoint.com/getting-started.aspx
- www.mysharepoint.com/files/folder1/admin-folder
- www.mysharepoint.com/contact-us.aspx
- etc...

I remember editing a permissions dialog of such nature, but a day after, I couldn't find it anymore. As I am not the ultimate super-admin of the site (eg. I can't activate certain site features such as Community Sites, but could do most of the other tasks), I suspect that the super-admin of the site somehow disabled it by accident.

I hope someone here can direct me in the right step.

Thank you!

---

*PS: I have discovered that you can customize a Page's permissions by User/Group by clicking on **Page Permissions** when you are viewing the page itself. Thus, you can't do this at the Settings page.

*PPS: To specify custom permissions for a particular file/folder, please refer to Jordan's kind answer below where you need to click on the **Share Details** when you view that specific item. Likewise, you can't do this in the Settings page.

The settings page is to allow you to define permission levels, rights and user groups. To specify fine grained permissions, you should visit that specific item/page and do it from there.

Answer (score 1):

To manage permissions of a site you would go to `Site Settings` -> `Site Permissions`.  From here you can manage who can read, edit, contribute, etc. across the whole site.

For your other examples it seems like you want to set permissions on a specific item (folder, web page).  For that you need to find the item in its library.  When you find it, click the ellipses twice (`...`) and click `Shared with`.  This will show you who the item is currently shared with.  If you want to break permissions on the item click `Advanced`.  From here you can stop inheriting permissions from the parent and use unique permissions for the item.

If you'd rather set permissions on a library or list rather than a list item you can do that as well in the library / list settings.

Remember by breaking the site permissions you are creating a lot more permissions that need to be maintained.  It is generally a good idea to not have to break permissions much.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know about this feature at all.